# Ubuntu 18.04 server and RAID - fakeRAID or hardware or mdadm

Tags: uefi, raid, mdadm

I'm unclear what my best option is to install Ubuntu 18.04 server onto a new machine.

I initially thought I'd be able to set up a RAID 1 mirror on my 2 SSDs in the UEFI menu and use that. Following the mobo instructions, I set up RAID using Intel RST in the UEFI menus, but the Ubuntu installer doesn't see the RAID mirror drive.

Reading up on this, I can't work out if this is hardware RAID or fakeRAID?

Either way, this doc https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html#software-raid says that linux software RAID with `mdadm` is superior anyway.

All the various pieces about whether the CPU is doing the work of the RAID or not are **not** self-explanatory, but my take on it is saying, actually a hardware RAID is best - only, is Intel RST RAID hardware RAID or fakeRAID?

And if the CPU isn't doing the work, what is? Some other component on the mobo?

Or have I been reading out-of-date stuff?

Answer (score 1):

This is fakeraid and only works with Windows because the raid software is built into the driver.  On linux, you want to disable any raid in the bios and set up mdraid.  You can set up mdraid using the alternate installer.  Unfortunately, I think Ubuntu stopped distributing the alternate installer disc images.  You might be able to set up the mdraid from the commandline and use the created raid devices in the installer.

Comment: OK, so I need to complain bitterly to Gigabyte that their RAID solution for NVMe SSDs is a big side-track and they need to concentrate on sorting out normal BIOS-based RAID software.

Comment: James, would you add some info to your answer about what the future has in store for hardware RAID in view of the rise of superfast SSD hard drives? Is hardware RAID dead as far as single PCs are concerned?